# Changing the 'Shipping' text in WooCommerce cart and checkout pages:

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

I'm using WooCommerce with the Storefront theme and I'm trying to alter the word **"Shipping"** on the basket page with totals.

I found some advice here: https://kriesi.at/support/topic/change-shipping-text-to-delivery-on-checkoutcart/

However, they mention it might require custom work to do this.

Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 12):

Add this hook in function.php

```html
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_package_name', 'custom_shipping_package_name' );
function custom_shipping_package_name( $name ) {
  return 'Your Text';
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Please add this code in functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_package_name', 'custom_shipping_package_name' );
function custom_shipping_package_name( $name ) {
    return 'Delivery';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing anything like that will require some custom code. There's a good tutorial here: https://apppresser.com/woocommerce-checkout-customization-guide/

However, if you're not confident with doing that, you can use one of the many plugins which are available. WooCommerce themselves do one: https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-checkout-field-editor/